# adding class in jquery on hover

Tags: jquery

On Hover I'm trying to add a class and to change image but my image still stay still on hover. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdiamond/dmb3w5ss/4/)

```
  $( "img.animation" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this )
      .attr('src', "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thoughtbot/refills/master/source/images/placeholder_logo_2.png")
      .addClass("animated fadeInDown");
    }, function() {
    $( this )
      .attr('src', "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thoughtbot/refills/master/source/images/placeholder_logo_1.png")
      .removeClass("animated fadeInDown").animate("slow");
    }
);
```

Comment: You have `image_animation` in the class for your images; I assume you meant that the `_` to be a space? `img.animation != img.image_animation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any `img.animation`

It looks great this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//http://api.jquery.com/hover/

    //changing logo
  $( ".grid-item" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this )
      .find('img')
      .attr('src', "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thoughtbot/refills/master/source/images/placeholder_logo_2.png")
      .addClass("animated fadeInDown");
    }, function() {
        //than slide it up
    $( this )
      .find('img')
      .attr('src', "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thoughtbot/refills/master/source/images/placeholder_logo_1.png")
      .removeClass("animated fadeInDown")
      .animate("slow");
    }
);

});//docu.ready
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
img.animation
```

To:

```
image_animation
```

You don't have any class named `img.animation`.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sLjokkod/)**